# SSRS Group by year

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a report with SSRS 2012 which is completely new to me that displays the totals of different shipment types and their date. I did manage to get rid of the time but I want it to just display the years and the totals of the shipment type. I have set it to group by date in design view. Any ideas how to pull this off would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of grouping by date, you can group by the expression `=Year(Fields!ShipDate.Value)` (or whatever your field is called), i.e. only grouping on the `Year` component of all the dates in your Dataset.